# Geolocation clearWatch(watchId) does not stop location tracking (React Native)

Tags: react-native, geolocation, react-hooks, react-functional-component, use-ref

I'm trying to create simple example of location tracker and I'm stuck with following case. My basic goal is to toggle location watch by pressing start/end button. I'm doing separation of concerns by implementing custom react hook which is then used in App component:

**useWatchLocation.js**

```
import {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react"
import {PermissionsAndroid} from "react-native"
import Geolocation from "react-native-geolocation-service"

const watchCurrentLocation = async (successCallback, errorCallback) => {
  if (!(await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))) {
    errorCallback("Permissions for location are not granted!")
  }
  return Geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {
    timeout: 3000,
    maximumAge: 500,
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    distanceFilter: 0,
    useSignificantChanges: false,
  })
}

const stopWatchingLocation = (watchId) => {
  Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId)
  // Geolocation.stopObserving()
}

export default useWatchLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState()
  const [lastError, setLastError] = useState()
  const [locationToggle, setLocationToggle] = useState(false)
  const watchId = useRef(null)

  const startLocationWatch = () => {
    watchId.current = watchCurrentLocation(
      (position) => {
        setLocation(position)
      },
      (error) => {
        setLastError(error)
      }
    )
  }

  const cancelLocationWatch = () => {
    stopWatchingLocation(watchId.current)
    setLocation(null)
    setLastError(null)
  }

  const setLocationWatch = (flag) => {
    setLocationToggle(flag)
  }

  // execution after render when locationToggle is changed
  useEffect(() => {
    if (locationToggle) {
      startLocationWatch()
    } else cancelLocationWatch()
    return cancelLocationWatch()
  }, [locationToggle])

  // mount / unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    cancelLocationWatch()
  }, [])

  return { location, lastError, setLocationWatch }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react"
import {Button, Text, View} from "react-native"

import useWatchLocation from "./hooks/useWatchLocation"

export default App = () => {
  const { location, lastError, setLocationWatch } = useWatchLocation()
  return (
    <View style={{ margin: 20 }}>
      <View style={{ margin: 20, alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>{location && `Time: ${new Date(location.timestamp).toLocaleTimeString()}`}</Text>
        <Text>{location && `Latitude: ${location.coords.latitude}`}</Text>
        <Text>{location && `Longitude: ${location.coords.longitude}`}</Text>
        <Text>{lastError && `Error: ${lastError}`}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 20, width: "100%", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
        <Button onPress={() => {setLocationWatch(true)}} title="START" />
        <Button onPress={() => {setLocationWatch(false)}} title="STOP" />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I have searched multiple examples which are online and code above should work. But the problem is when stop button is pressed location still keeps getting updated even though I invoke **Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId)**.

I wrapped Geolocation calls to handle location permission and other possible debug stuff. It seems like **watchId** value that is saved using **useRef** hook inside **useWatchLocation** is invalid. My guess is based on attempting to call **Geolocation.stopObserving()** right after Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId). Subscription stops but I get warning:

> Called stopObserving with existing subscriptions.

So I assume that original subscription was not cleared.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

EDIT: I figured out solution. But since isMounted pattern is generally considered antipattern: Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, problem solved with **isMounted pattern**. isMounted.current is set at `locationToggle` effect to `true` and inside `cancelLocationWatch` to `false`:

```
const isMounted = useRef(null)

...
    
useEffect(() => {
        if (locationToggle) {
          isMounted.current = true              // <--
          startLocationWatch()
        } else cancelLocationWatch()
        return () => cancelLocationWatch()
      }, [locationToggle])
    
...    

const cancelLocationWatch = () => {
        stopWatchingLocation(watchId.current)
        setLocation(null)
        setLastError(null)
        isMounted.current = false               // <--
      }
```

And checked at mount / unmount effect, success and error callback:

```
const startLocationWatch = () => {
    watchId.current = watchCurrentLocation(
      (position) => {
        if (isMounted.current) {                // <--
          setLocation(position)
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        if (isMounted.current) {                // <--
          setLastError(error)
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: I think this is a justified use case for the `isMounted` pattern